# left right alignment for key-pair value in bootstrap

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

Lets say I have the following:

```
        <div class="card">
            <ul class="list-group list-group-flush ">
                <li class="list-group-item" style="border: none;">
                    <strong>Something</strong> : 12333434
                </li>
                <li class="list-group-item" style="border: none">
                    <strong>Something else</strong>: 2837487248723847283
                </li>
                <li class="list-group-item" style="border: none">
                    <strong>Some other stuff</strong>: 123442342423423
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
```

Above looks like the following in browser:

[image]

However ideally I want it to look like the following (ignore the font change. I only care about the alignment):

[image]

Meaning the left side gets aligned to the right while the right side text gets aligned to the left. 
How can I achieve this in bootstrap?

Answer (score 6):

Using `inline-block` this can be achieved.By default `strong` is `inline`.

```
strong{
  display:inline-block;
  width:200px;
  text-align:right;
}
```

Here is the fiddle [link](https://jsfiddle.net/ho504fgm/2/)

Comment: That's not what I want. I want all those <strong>Something</strong> to be aligned to the right just like the second picture. What you sent me doesn't look like it.

Comment: For future readers for @MHOOS query we need to use: `text-align:left;`

Answer (score 1):

Something like this would work, but requires set widths:

HTML:

```
<div class="card text-center">
  <ul class="list-group list-group-flush">
    <li class="list-group-item">
      <div class="list-group-item-fixed">
        <strong class="list-group-left">Something:</strong>
        <span class="list-group-right">12333434</span>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li class="list-group-item">
      <div class="list-group-item-fixed">
        <strong class="list-group-left">Something else:</strong>
        <span class="list-group-right">2837487248723847283</span>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li class="list-group-item">
      <div class="list-group-item-fixed">
        <strong class="list-group-left">Some other stuff:</strong>
        <span class="list-group-right">123442342423423</span>
      </div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.list-group-item-fixed {
  width: auto;
}
.list-group-left {
  text-align: right;
  width: 150px;
  font-weight: bold;
  display: inline-block;
}
.list-group-right {
  text-align: left;
  width: 200px;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/6nxtyv7b/

However, if you don't need a list, a simple table would suffice, and wouldn't need set widths:

HTML:

```
<div class="text-center">
  <table class="table table-borderless table-centralised">
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <th>Something:</th>
        <td>12333434</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>Something else:</th>
        <td>2837487248723847283</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>Some other stuff:</th>
        <td>123442342423423</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.table-centralised {
  width: 0 auto;
}
.table-centralised th {
  text-align: right;
  width: auto;
}
.table-centralised td {
  text-align: left;
  width: auto;
}
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/m06ek73u/